# Is there a way to replace a class using renderer2 in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-renderer2

I am using angular 10 and using Renderer2 to add and remove classes:

```
this.renderer.removeClass(this.document.body, 'signin-user');
this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, 'anonymous-user');
```

Does Renderer2 let me replace a class. For e.g if "signin-user" is applied replace it with "anonymous-user" and vice-versa instead of writing the removeClass function.

Comment: No, there isn't a method to do directly via `Renderer2`. You can write a common method to do that, of course.

Comment: No, you can't, it's straight forward though.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.renderer2.addClass(element, 'className');
this.renderer2.removeClass(element, 'className');
```

You can check this out [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#removeClass)